# How to point to a geom_label with a geom_segment?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's start with this toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)


nodes=data.frame(x = c(30, 50, 72, 35, 48, 70), 
                 y = c(90, 65, 93, 15, 37, 10), 
                 label = c("box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box5","box6"))
links=data.frame(x = c(50, 72, 48, 70, 48), 
                 y = c(65, 93, 37, 10, 37), 
                 xend = c(30, 50, 35, 48, 50), 
                 yend = c(90, 65, 15, 37, 65), 
                 startname = c("box2", "box3", "box5", "box6", "box5"), 
                 endname = c("box1", "box2", "box4", "box5", "box2"))




gg<-ggplot(nodes, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_segment(data=links, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
  geom_label(aes(label=label)) + xlim(0, 100) + ylim(0,100) +
  theme_void()+ theme(legend.position = "none")
gg
```

[image]

In this case I'm already making sure to have the segments come before the labels so that the labels will be on top of the segments giving the appearance that the line is going to the label.  That's fine here, but what I really want to do is point to one of the boxes so I need the points that make up the exterior of the label box.  I've seen similar questions which use the `ggrepel` package but that solves the problem 'how to keep the label from interfering with data points?' but I want to make the label the center of attraction.

I tried converting `gg` into grob.  I looked at `str(ggplotGrob(gg)$grobs[[5]]$children[[4]]$children[[1]])` which was promising as it starts with:

```
List of 13
$ label        : chr "box1"
$ x            : 'simpleUnit' num 0.318native
..- attr(*, "unit")= int 4
$ y            : 'simpleUnit' num 0.864native
..- attr(*, "unit")= int 4
```

where that `(.318, .864)` is close to the first point of `(30,90)` if divided by 100.  From there though it's not clear where to go.

I did `grid::grobCoords(ggplotGrob(gg)$grobs[[5]]$children[[4]]$children[[1]], TRUE)` but the coordinates make even less sense to me...

```
gTree GRID.labelgrob.13779 
grob box  
shape 1 
x: -0.1781439 0.1847727 0.1835647 ... [51 values]
y: 7.597254 7.597254 7.597278 ... [51 values]
grob text  
shape 1 
x: -0.1581439 -0.1581439 0.1647727 ... [4 values]
y: 7.647254 7.772254 7.772254 ... [4 values]
```

That's just the route I tried to find a way to point to the label.  If there's another way that doesn't involve grobs then that's fine too.  I thought about just creating `geom_rect`s and and putting `geom_text` on top of them since it's defined by the boundary rather than center point so then I automatically know the boundary location of the rect.  The problem with that approach is I don't know how big to make the `geom_rect` to fit the text.

Comment: Just a suggestion, maybe you can use `nchar(label)` plus some factor to adjust the `geom_rect()` coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are trying to get the co-ordinates of the label box outlines expressed as user co-ordinates. The problem here is that if you shrink or expand your plotting window, the labels stay the same size. This has the effect of changing their co-ordinates. Even trying to do this via grob-hacking runs into the same problem.

Since you are using `theme_void`, you could make your plot fill the whole window by setting `expand = c(0, 0)` on both your x and y scales, which along with your axis limits, makes it straightforward to convert plotting space into user space.

```r
gg <- ggplot(nodes, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_segment(data=links, aes(xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = label)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

gg
```

[image]

Now we measure device size in millimetres:

```r
dev_size <- dev.size(units = "cm") * 10
```

We can now measure the height from the centre of the label to its top / bottom edge. This relies on the calculation that the font size is 11, that 1 pt = 0.352778mm, that from top to bottom of the plot is 100 in user space (our y axis), that the spacing around the box is 0.25 of a line width:

```
label_height <- 100 * (11 * 0.352778 * 0.75) / dev_size[2]
```

This allows us to plot segments that touch the upper edge of our labels (we prove that here by drawing arrows on them)

```r
gg + geom_segment(aes(xend = x, y = y + 5, yend = y + label_height),
                  color = "red", arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, "mm")))
```

[image]

We can do the same for the lateral edges of the boxes, but we would need to use the `strwidth` function to measure the size of each string then perform a similar calculation.

Note also, that if you resize your plot after it is drawn, the arrows will not line up, and their position will need to be recalculated.